# Error al inicial el inicial el sercicio SQL SERVER BROWSER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

despues de cambiarle el nombre a mi pc sqlServer dejo de funcionar, y cuando intento inicial el servicio sqlbrowser no me deje.

Comment: añlade por favor el error que te esta mostrando

Comment: no me muestra nada, solo que cuando voy a a iniciar el servicio este aparece disable el boton para iniciarlo

Comment: ¿Y si le regresas el nombre a la computadora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para un equipo renombrado que aloja una instancia predeterminada de SQL Server, ejecuta los siguientes SP's para cambiar el nombre del servidor:

```
sp_dropserver <old_name>;
GO
sp_addserver <new_name>, local;
GO
```

Si estás cambiando el nombre del servidor SQL, también debe cambiar el nombre del servidor físico para no confundir las cosas.
La capa física es lo que permite al usuario conectarse utilizando el nombre de red o DNS. Sin cambiar ese nombre, cambiar la referencia interna de SQL Server no tiene sentido ya que no podría encontrar el nombre en la red. Puede referirse a él todavía como el nombre antiguo y podría conectarse con el nombre antiguo o la dirección IP. Sin embargo, las cosas se confunden cuando intenta hacer referencia a la instalación SQL renombrada.

Para verificar que se renombró correctamente el server puedes utilizar el siguiente select:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name';
```

En cuanto al `sqlbrowser`, si está deshabilitado, ve a `Panel de control-> Herramientas administrativas-> Servicios`, busca el Agente de SQL Server (`SQL Server Agent`). Haz clic derecho y selecciona Propiedades en el menú desplegable Tipo de inicio, cambie de Deshabilitado a Automático.

Espero te ayude ésta información.